# Gradle docker container ignores cache when started from Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, caching, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I am running a build in a gradle container with a volume for the cache, but gradle does not make use of the downloaded dependencies in the cache for the subsequent builds.

Here's the dockerfile for the gradle image:

```
FROM **custom image base**

# Install the Java Development Kit
RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk8=8.131.11-r2

CMD ["gradle"]

ENV GRADLE_HOME /opt/gradle
ENV GRADLE_VERSION 4.6

ARG GRADLE_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=98bd5fd2b30e070517e03c51cbb32beee3e2ee1a84003a5a5d748996d4b1b915
RUN set -o errexit -o nounset \
        && echo "Installing build dependencies" \
        && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
                ca-certificates \
                openssl \
                unzip \
        \
        && echo "Downloading Gradle" \
        && wget -O gradle.zip "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip" \
        \
        && echo "Checking download hash" \
        && echo "${GRADLE_DOWNLOAD_SHA256} *gradle.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
        \
        && echo "Installing Gradle" \
        && unzip gradle.zip \
        && rm gradle.zip \
        && mkdir /opt \
        && mv "gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}" "${GRADLE_HOME}/" \
        && ln -s "${GRADLE_HOME}/bin/gradle" /usr/bin/gradle \
        \
        && apk del .build-deps \
        \
        && echo "Adding gradle user and group" \
        && addgroup -S -g 1000 gradle \
        && adduser -D -S -G gradle -u 1000 -s /bin/ash gradle \
        && mkdir /home/gradle/.gradle \
        && chown -R gradle:gradle /home/gradle \
        \
        && echo "Symlinking root Gradle cache to gradle Gradle cache" \
        && ln -s /home/gradle/.gradle /root/.gradle

# Create Gradle volume
USER gradle
VOLUME "/home/gradle/.gradle"
WORKDIR /home/gradle

RUN set -o errexit -o nounset \
        && echo "Testing Gradle installation" \
        && gradle --version
```

In the Jenkinsfile I have the build stage declared like this:

```
stage('Build') {
        docker.image('custom-gradle').withRun('-v gradle-cache:/home/gradle/.gradle') { c ->
            docker.image('custom-gradle').inside {
                sh './scripts/build.py -br ' + branchName
                sh 'cp build/libs/JARFILE*.jar build/libs/JARFILE.jar'
            }
        }
    }
```

The 'gradle-cache' volume is a volume that was created with the docker volume create command.

The python script just runs a gradle command:

```
gradle clean assemble javaDoc
```

When I inspect the gradle-cache volume data on the host machine it contains the following files/folders:

```
4.6  buildOutputCleanup  caches  daemon  native
```

So the build successfully writes to the cache volume, but appears not to read from it, re-downloading every dependency for every build.

How can I get gradle to use these downloaded dependencies?

**UPDATE**

```
stage('Build Bag End') {
        docker.image('custom-gradle').inside('-v gradle-cache:/home/gradle/.gradle') {
            sh './scripts/build.py -br ' + branchName
            sh 'cp build/libs/JARFILE*.jar build/libs/JARFILE.jar'
        }
    }
```

So I found the .inside() command also supports parameters but it still won't read from the cache; only write to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Jenkins Docker Plugin always runs containers as the `jenkins` user. It looks like your gradle image is assuming that it is running as the `gradle` user. You might try adding the following option:

```
-e GRADLE_USER_HOME=/home/gradle/.gradle
```

Though you might run into permission issues with that.